# A work around for having a role that can report to at least 2 other roles?

Tags: role-hierarchy

I want to create a role `child` that reports to `Parent1` and `Parent2`. If I create `child` under `Parent1` I cannot create `child` under `Parent2`. It says: `Error: This Role Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name.`

Is there a way (a work around, as we cannot have multiple parent roles for a single child role) to create a child role that answers to multiple parent roles?

Comment: Please specify the purpose (reporting, visibility, etc.). Depending on that, the work-around might differ.

Comment: @SergioAlcocer For visibility purpose

Answer (score 2):

A role can only report to one other role. If you need additional flexibility, you might want to use [Territory Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/territory-management-basics/get-started-with-enterprise-territory-management) or, if you just need visibility, you can simply create a [Sharing Rule](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/create-opportunity-sharing-rules). The latter allows you to share records owned by one role with users in another role, and is far easier to set up for simple use cases. TM should only be considered if you need the advanced power, as once enabled, you can't disable it later.